# Extensions in Magento 2.2.2 error

Tags: error, extensions, magento2.2, installation

This is my first question, I'm sorry if this problem has been solved or if I am doing anything wrong.

My problem is that every time I try to activate an extension, in Extension Manager,  i get the error:

> [ErrorException]
>
> chdir(): Permission denied (errno 13)

I am not sure what directory that needs permission?
Thank you

EDIT:
I am posting this here, because it is not only 1 extension, but all extensions that give this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set permission for pub/static and var folder.

run below command from magento root,

```
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \;
find var pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \;
```

Comment: unfortunately, that did not work... i still get the same error.